# placing my social icons in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been adding social icons to the top of my webpage, i have been able to add 3 so far horizontally but not when ever i try and add another it just wont show, please would you look at my code if there is any mistakes, Thankyou

CSS;

```
#social  {
top:18px;
left:15px;
height:32px;
width:500px;
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
}

.facebook {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.facebook:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/facebook_active.png);
}
.twitter {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/twitter_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.twitter:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/twitter_active.png);
}
.in {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/in_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.in:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/in_active.png);
}
.youtube {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/youtube_dark.png);
height:32px;
width:32px;
background-size:32px;
display:inline-block;
}
.youtube:hover {
background-image:url(../img/64_x_64px/youtube_active.png);
}
```

HTML;

```
<body>
<div id="social">
<div class="facebook"></div>
<div class="twitter"></div>
<div class="in"></div>
<div class="youtube"></div>
</div>
<div id="logo">
</div>
<div id="bar">
</div>
<div id="middle">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thankyou for your help !

Comment: I think it has to do with your width: 500px, maybe the last social icon is exceeding that limit.

Comment: Seconding @TheMiniJohn

Comment: I would fourth that, but each icon is 32px wide, `32 * 4 = 128 != 500`

Comment: What does that mean people ?

Comment: Are you sure that the icon is in the correct folder and named appropriately?

Comment: Thanks for helping me all, this is really annoying me, ive been trying for hours ahah i have no idea what the problem is

Comment: Yeah, it's [working fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Tj4jH/).

Comment: @DaveZych you're correct!

Comment: Did you check if it's not hiding behind any other element? or if there is any problem with image? so first make #social position:relative; for testing and then check again. and to make it confirm that there is no problem with youtube img, repeat first facebook div four times for testing and then have a look.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be working fine.

Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9uh4/1/)

I added the following tag to the buttons:

```
float:left;
```

But it was working ok on my browser, even before.
Maybe you are simply missing the 4th image?

Hope this helps!